# Laptops to Install Ubuntu

Tags: laptop

what are some good laptop options for me to install Linux Ubuntu into?

Thank you,

Sinan

P.S. I am a new to Ubuntu.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/

Comment: Ubuntu works at least for 99% of all laptops. It is easier to know what hardware requirements the different flavors have and with that in mind you choose which laptop to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest distributions of Ubuntu pretty much support whatever machine you can find with out much or any tinkering.

I use a samsung chronos 7 which comes from the factory with windows 8 and UEFI which is supposed to lock you into using windows, but even this hasn't been a problem.

The thing your most likely going to encounter is that every other machine you use will have some minor quirk, but these are usually taken care of pretty quickly.

I'm not sure about Mac's, I hear it's a little more difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. What laptop options you have in mind?

Comment: I mean really, whatever laptop you have access to. If you have an older one that your not using for critical stuff, like work, development, art, whatever.. try the install on that and tour around with that. Then after your comfortable, pick any machine you want, really, Ubuntu will work directly for *almost* any laptop you can obtain.